# how to get a list of users with their respective roles?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, blazor-webassembly

How can I get the identity users with their multiple assigned roles, I want the user's name and a list of roles to be seen, i am using blazor wasm and aspnet core.
so far I have this, but I don't know if I'm on the right track or there are other alternatives instead of using projection:

```
var listado = await (from user in context.Users
                         join userRoles in context.UserRoles on user.Id equals userRoles.UserId
                         join role in context.Roles on userRoles.RoleId equals role.Id
                         select new { UserId = user.Id, UserName = user.UserName, RoleId = role.Id, RoleName = role.Name })
                        .ToListAsync();
```

With this code I get that each user is assigned their roles, but a user has more than one role and generates it for me 3 times, when I want the user to be generated once with his list of roles

Answer (score 0):

Widely answered here: [Group by in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq).
Check Jon Skeet's answer. Your roles would be the cars in that example.